# javaScript (image) variable to php variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javaScript and I found this java script on the internet for previewing images.
I cannot send the java variable for the image to the php file. I have tried using the html box but cannot get the variable into php. I have also tried using reader.onload, new FileReader, #blah, blar ect as variables in the html field but no of these seem to act as the variable (also tried it without the echo statement). Any pointers on this will be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerzyui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input)
{
      if (input.files && input.files[0])
              {
                   var reader = new FileReader();
                   reader.onload = function (e)
                                          {
                                                $('#blah')
                                                .attr('src',e.target.result)
                                                .width(150)
                                                .height(200);
                                          };
                   reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                   }
}
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://goo.gl/r57ze"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' onChange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="Image Name" width="10" height="10" />
</body>
</html>


this is the submit box

<form action="file.php" method="post" >
  <input type="hidden" id="name"  value="<?php echo reader ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? You should make up your mind.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to do as it doesnt make sense. are you trying to post an image upload to a php script? are you trying to upload a image and have it show in the `img` tag? where is your form? (and please don't get java and javascript confused)

Comment: you file input isnt inside your form? you also need a multipart attribute in there for file uploading

Comment: You need a form tag.